# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in blogger template

Tags: blogger

I have used custom blogger template, I got error in console that said `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I have used some template and on it's blog all things working fine. But when I use that same template then it shows error in console. When I inspected the console then I found that some JS files are still not loading in the browser saying `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

**Snapshot of console.**

[image]

**URL for tableview.js**

```
https://yourjavascript.com/013120251122/tabview.js
```

When the above url is browse then it shows the JS code without any issue. But blogger didn't find that external JS file at all.

> So how can I solve this issue? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have same question but I found that I was using GraphQl in my project and in ApolloProvider I gave uri i.e https://localhost:8888/.netlifyfunctions/function_name. So when project was live it cannot access localhost. so in simple you should change that uri to /.netlify/functions/function_name.

Thanks